# $T$ is self-adjoint on $L^2$ and $T^4$ is a compact operator, will $T$ be compact on $L^2?$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators, adjoint-operators

> Let $K^*$ be a self-adjoint operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3),$ and assume $(K^*)^4 := K^* \circ K^* \circ K^* \circ K^*$ is a [Hilbert-Schmidt operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator) on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3).$

> Will $K^*$ be a compact operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)?$

I ask this question because I am reading the proof for Theorem 2.1 of [the paper of Golse and Poupaud](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/mma.1670110406). The following is its proof.

[image]

I guess this is true. But I can't provide a rigorous proof here.

Heuristically, since $(K^∗)^4$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator, it's compact. Then, with its self-adjointness, $(K^∗)^4$ is similar to a diagonalized infinite matrix D (by spectral theorem) and its trace is finite. So $K^∗$ looks like a diagonalized matrix $\sqrt[4]{D}.$ (Here, we use the self-adjointness of $K^*$ to ensure $(K^∗)^4$ is nonnegative). Then we see the operator $K^∗$ can be approximated by truncating $\sqrt[4]{D}$ to finite matrices.

I am appreciated to any discussion and hint.

Comment: You seem to be confusing self adjointness with positive definiteness. $D$ need not be positive. My functional analysis is a bit rusty, but I think what you can do is look at the spectral decomposition of $K$ and note that if it is not HS, then neither is $K^4$.

Comment: @tomasz I think the argument is that since $K$ is self-adjoint, $K^2=K^*K$ and $D=K^4=K^2(K^2)^*$ must be nonnegative.

Comment: @supinf: You're right. I misunderstood the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T$ be a bounded self adjoint operator on a Hilbert space (to avoid the notation $K^*$ which looks like the adjoint of the operator $K$) and suppose that $T^n$ is compact for some positive integer $n$ (such as $n=4$).
Then $T$ is compact.

The reason is as follows: $T^{2n}$ is positive and compact and hence so is $(T^{2n})^{1/p}$ for every $p>0$.  Moreover
$$
T = \lim_{p\to\infty} (T^{2n})^{1/p}T,
$$
So $T$
is also compact.

Comment: Could you explain the definition of $(T^{2n})^{1/p}$ you used here and how to use it to show $(T^{2n})^{1/p}$ is compact? Thank you.

Comment: This is based on the *functional calculus* for self-adjoint operators.  It asserts that there exists an isometric
isomorphism $$ \Lambda : C(\sigma(T))\to B(H) $$ that sends the function "$f(x)=x$" to $T$, and the constant function
"$f(x)=1$" to the identity operator.

If $f\in C(\sigma(T))$, people often write $f(T)$ in place of $\Lambda(f)$, so that $(T^{2n})^{1/p}$ refers to
$\Lambda(f)$, where $f$ is the function "$f(x)=(x^{2n})^{1/p}$".  I suggest you study this theory if you haven'd done
so, because it is the most powerful too to deal with self-adjoint operators ever invented!

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the late reply. I think your method is doable. What I was confused is the following question: Does $T^4$ defined by the Cauchy integral formula (from wiki page of holomorphic functional calculus) equals to the 4-times composition of "bounded" self-adjoint operator T? But I can prove it now.

Comment: Thanks!  I am glad you figured out all of the details!  Indeed all known types of "functional calculus", namely polynomial, holomorphic, continuous or Borel, are extremely useful mainly because they entail a **homomorphism** from some algebra of functions on the spectrum to the algebra of operators!